# MosChip 9865 serial card

Tags: linux, serial-port

I just bought a new serial port card but I have  been unable to get it working, it does appear in lspci and dmesg, but when I send data through it I don't receive it back on the other port (I'm connecting both ports together with a DB-9 cable).

dmesg | grep tty:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.810197] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.831771] 0000:04:07.0: ttyS1 at I/O 0xc130 (irq = 21, base_baud = 115200) is a ST16650V2
[    0.853172] 0000:04:07.1: ttyS2 at I/O 0xc120 (irq = 22, base_baud = 115200) is a ST16650V2
[    0.860203] tty ttyS1: hash matches
```

lspci -v:

```
04:07.0 Serial controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Device a000:1000
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 21, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at c130 [size=8]
    Memory at fe105000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fe104000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial
    Kernel modules: parport_pc

04:07.1 Serial controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCI 9865 Multi-I/O Controller (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Device a000:1000
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 22, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at c120 [size=8]
    Memory at fe103000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fe102000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial
    Kernel modules: parport_pc

04:07.2 Parallel controller: Illegal Vendor ID Device 9865 (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
    Subsystem: Device a000:2000
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at c110 [disabled] [size=8]
    I/O ports at c100 [disabled] [size=8]
    Memory at fe101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Memory at fe100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Note: I'm running Parabola GNU/Linux-libre 64 bits

Comment: Have you worked with serial ports before? Do you know the difference between a straight-through cable and a null-modem cable, and which one you need for the current situation?

Comment: No I haven't nor I know which one I need for this situation, I hadn't thought about it sorry. I guess I should feel a little bit stupid ...

Comment: I though a little better what I was doing and deceided to try to connect an LED (with a resistor of course) to the transmit pin and the ground of it to the port ground, sent some data, and yes the led turned on so in theory the port is working. I really feel stupid now, well at least I got it working ..., thanks for your comment.